# Does a Cleric with high Wisdom get all their bonus spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, cleric

How do bonus spells work?

Bob is a Level 2 Cleric with a 16 Wisdom.

The class table grants him the following spells per day

[O:4]
[L1:2+1]

But his high casting stat grants him the following Bonus spells per day

[O:0]
[L1:1]
[L2:1]
[L3:1]

What is the earliest level that Bob can cast a level 2 spell?

Is there a citation for this in the actual rules?

Answer (score 9):

### In short, No.

To quote [Pathfinder's FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748btpy88yj/faq#v5748eaic9o91):

> **Bonus Spells from a High Ability Score: Can I use these even if my spellcasting class level isn't high enough to give me access to those spell levels?**
>
> No. You only get the bonus spells if your class level grants you access to those spell levels. You can't even use them for lower-level spells. See page 16, Abilities and Spellcasters section: "In addition to having a high ability score, a spellcaster must be of a high enough class level to be able to cast spells of a given spell level. "
>
> For example, a 1st-level wizard with 18 Intelligence has (according to table 1–3: Ability Modifiers and Bonus Spells) 1 bonus spell at spell levels 1, 2, and 3. However, he can only use the 1st-level bonus spell because as a 1st-level wizard he only has access to 1st-level spells (his class-based number of 2nd- and 3rd-level spells per day are "—", meaning "no access to spells of this level"). As soon as he becomes a 3rd-level wizard, he gains access to his 2nd-level spell slots and can use that bonus 2nd-level spell slot from his high Intelligence, and likewise for 3rd-level spells and bonus spells at wizard level 5.
>
> Basically, ignore the columns for higher-level spells on table 1–3: Ability Modifiers and Bonus Spells until your class grants you access to those spell levels.